# Automatic wake up from "sleep" of kubuntu after ssh connection attempt

Tags: linux, sleep, kubuntu, wake-up

Is there a way to set Kubuntu up so that it wakes up automatically from sleep mode upon ssh connection attempt? I know there is something like WoL, but that's not what I need (am I right?).

Comment: I think you need WOL to do it

Comment: @Fivesheep how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before ssh, you have to send a wol magic package from a machine which is in the same lan with your kubuntu system. it depends on what device you have, it can be a computer or router. for ubuntu, you can install "wakeonlan".

make sure you have wol enabled in your motherboard's bios settings

Comment: It dont really need to be in the same LAN. You can send Magic packets over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

For those running [Tomato by Shibby](http://tomato.groov.pl/?page_id=164), other Tomato based, or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) firmware on their router, you could write a little script to automatically wake up any PC on your local network that receives a new connection on its SSH port. I've [written about this on my blog](http://blog.oxplot.com/wake-up-on-ssh/) and the code is on [github gist](https://gist.github.com/oxplot/75d4bbbe0c782cc8a8b2).